# ActiveMQ: How to send same group of messages to one consumer thread

Tags: mule, activemq-classic, mulesoft

We are using ActiveMQ in our project we have a requirement that a group of
messages which belongs to one group should be consumed by one consumer
thread.

For instance, we have 3 (M1, M2, M3) messages which belong to person A and 3 (M4, M5, M6) messages which belong to person B.

Our requirement is: all messages belongs to person A should be consumed by
consumer thread 1 and all messages belongs to person B should be consumed by
consumer thread 2.

Based on the ActiveMQ documentation and per our understanding, we have used
JMXGroupId concept in ActiveMQ. For instance, we have set `JMSXGroupId` as
`123` for all messages (M1, M2, M3) belonging to person A and `234` for all
messages (M4, M5, M6) belonging to person B.

With `JMXGroupId` in some cases all messages belonging to person A & B (M1, M2, M3, M4, M5 , & M6) are going to same consumer thread 1. But in  our requirement it should be going to two different threads.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this subject has been [discussed before](http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/Message-Group-rebalancing-td4703823.html) on the ActiveMQ User Mailing List. That discussion resulted in [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-2106), and it appears the solution to that issue involves sending a message with a `JMSXGroupSeq` property whose value is `-1`. As stated on the Jira:

> The key to rebalance, now that group load is part of consumer priority, is periodic group termination using a negative sequence number property. message.setIntProperty("JMSXGroupSeq", -1);

Unfortunately there appears to be a problem with this implementation which is summarized on [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-3027). That issue was reported in late 2010 (i.e. 10 years ago now) and it appears that nothing has been done to resolve it since.

Therefore, I see three different options for you:

1. Fix the issue in the [ActiveMQ code-base](https://github.com/apache/activemq) yourself. This is one of the great benefits of Open Source software - you can fix bugs and implement features you need for yourself without having to wait on anybody else.
2. Move to [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) which already supports this feature as noted in [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/message-grouping.html#rebalancing-message-groups). ActiveMQ Artemis is the next generation broker from ActiveMQ and is slated to become ActiveMQ 6 when it reaches sufficient feature parity. ActiveMQ Artemis supports all the same protocols as ActiveMQ 5.x so you won't need to change any of your clients.
3. Ditch message grouping and simply use selectors on your consumers. For example, every message belonging to person 1 can have a property named `personIndex` with a value of `1` and the consumer which should receive those messages can use a selector like `personIndex = 1` and then every message belonging to person 2 can have a property named `personIndex` with a value of `2` and the consumer which should receive those messages can use a selector like `personIndex = 2`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. we thought of implementing option 3 earlier but the challenge which we are facing is we may get various people related messages and Hence, If I need to set the Index I may have to go with some huge number and also I need to create that many inbound connectors each fine uses one selector filter.

Comment: something like this I need to create in mule<jms:inbound-endpoint queue="syncpoc" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS Priority 1">
               <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" />
               **<jms:selector expression="JMSPriority = 1"/>**
        </jms:inbound-endpoint>

Comment: <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="syncpoc" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS Priority 2">
               <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" />
               **<jms:selector expression="JMSPriority = 2"/>**
        </jms:inbound-endpoint><jms:inbound-endpoint queue="syncpoc" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS Priority 3">
               <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" />
               **<jms:selector expression="JMSPriority = 3"/>**
        </jms:inbound-endpoint> if you see number inbound end points would increase exponentially in my code.

Comment: I guess that rules out option 3 so that leaves options 1 & 2 as potential resolutions.